# Vtk.js: Import multi STLs

Tags: javascript, vtk.js

I'm using [Vtk.js](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/) to display 3D content on a web interface.

My problem happens when I try to load multiple models ([STL format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format))).

I'm using this logic:

PS: *files is an array of attributes of my STLs, the 'url' attribute is the path of the STL*

```
const fullScreenRenderer = vtk.Rendering.Misc.vtkFullScreenRenderWindow.newInstance();

for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var mapper = vtk.Rendering.Core.vtkMapper.newInstance({ scalarVisibility: false });
    var actor = vtk.Rendering.Core.vtkActor.newInstance();
    var reader = vtk.IO.Geometry.vtkSTLReader.newInstance();

    actor.setMapper(mapper);
    mapper.setInputConnection(reader.getOutputPort());

    actor.getProperty().setColor( files[i].color );
    actor.getProperty().setOpacity( files[i].opacity );

    fullScreenRenderer.getRenderer().addActor(actor);

    reader.setUrl( files[i].url , { binary: true }).then( update) ;
}

function update()
{  
    fullScreenRenderer.getRenderer().resetCamera();
    fullScreenRenderer.getRenderer().setLayer(1);
    fullScreenRenderer.getRenderWindow().render();
}
```

The problem is that every 3D model is black. If I remove the `setLayer(1)`, the whole screen is black.

I think this happend because I'm not using the correct "[pipeline](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CS526/Tutorial/VTK_Pipeline.jpg)". But I don't have that much experience with this library to know, the doc is still not complete, it is not helping.

Comment: It's been a while since I used VTK, and I've yet to try VTK.js. But if memory serves me right, standard STL format contains no color information. So what happens if you set a static color e.g actor.getProperty().setColor(1.0000, 0.3882, 0.2784); ?

Comment: That's what I'm doing. And it was working when I used server-side code to load the STLs but another errors where appearing like `No input` because I tried to load the model as the were not yet fully loaded.

That's why I'm searching for the "correct" workflow. I don't not even know if I have to declare the `vtkFullScreenRenderWindow` at the begining

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (but I don't understand why at all...)

```
const fullScreenRenderer = vtk.Rendering.Misc.vtkFullScreenRenderWindow.newInstance();

var actors = [];


for (var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var mapper = vtk.Rendering.Core.vtkMapper.newInstance({ scalarVisibility: false });
    actors[i] = vtk.Rendering.Core.vtkActor.newInstance();
    var reader = vtk.IO.Geometry.vtkSTLReader.newInstance();

    actors[i].setMapper(mapper);
    mapper.setInputConnection(reader.getOutputPort());

    actors[i].getProperty().setColor( files[i].color );
    actors[i].getProperty().setOpacity( files[i].opacity );

    fullScreenRenderer.getRenderer().addActor(actor);

    reader.setUrl( files[i].url , { binary: true }).then( update(i) ) ;
}

function update(i)
{  
    actors[i].getProperty().setColor( files[i].color );
    fullScreenRenderer.getRenderer().resetCamera();
    fullScreenRenderer.getRenderWindow().render();
}
```